# Identify and move data containing special characters to a separate column

Tags: qgis, expression, filter, list, regular-expression

My dataset contains special characters. I want to identify the data which contains special characters and separate it into a new column.

List of special characters :

```
`~!@#$%^&*_{}[]<>?/
```

Below are examples of the data:

[image]

I want the data to be separated as the above mentioned table, is there any way to do it?

Comment: `regexp_match` `regexp_substr` try something

Comment: What is, in your example, a "special character? Is it the `@`? Is it the apostrophe?

I'm afraid you cannot filter by "special character " without defining first what a special character is.

Comment: Apart from the question what a specil character is, you should also make clear what exaclty the result should look like. Which part of the string do you want to "separate into a new column", e.g. using your first example `1.KFC@Hyderabad-Hitech city`. Best would be to show us how the results from your list of examples should look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a discrepancy between the list of special characters and the example.  Specifically, a single quote or apostrophe isn't in the list, but yet `Burgers's` in the example is supposed to be caught by the filter.

My impression is that only a space and letters, possibly a hyphen/minus, should be excluded and everything else considered "special":

```
case
when regexp_match("Content", '[^\\p{L} ]') then "Content"
end
```

If you want to exclude numbers as well, then go with the following:

```
case
when regexp_match("Content", '[^\\p{L}\\p{N} ]') then "Content"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this expression. It copies the content of attribute field `text` if it contains everything else than characters a-z (upper- and lowercase), numbers or whitespaces (if needed, add further values you want to treat as regular/non-special character after `\\s`):

```
case 
when regexp_match ("text",'([^a-zA-Z0-9\\s])') > 0
then "text"
end
```

[image]